# Can Not Instantiate Object

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a `FlashCard` object in my `CardSet` class. The problem is that My `FlashCard` object cannot be instantiated. Neither of my classes are abstract nor they are interfaces.

Error occurs at line 19 of the CardSet Class:
this.add(new FlashCard(term, definition));
.

```
public class CardSet<FlashCard> extends LinkedList<FlashCard> {


private String nameOfSet;
private FlashCard activeCard;
private String term;
private String definition;


public CardSet(String nameOfSet)
{
    this.nameOfSet = nameOfSet;
}


public void addCard(String term, String definition)
{
    this.term = term;
    this.definition = definition;
    // cannot instantiate
    this.add(new FlashCard(term, definition));
}


}
```

```
public class FlashCard {

    private String definition;
    private String term;


    public FlashCard(String term, String definition)
    {
        this.term = term;
        this.defintion = definition;
    }

    public String getTerm()
    {
        return term;
    }

    public String getDefintion()
    {
        return definition;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: "Favour composition over inheritance" - in that scenario it seems a bit over the top to extend a Collection. Having a List of cards as a member of your cardset is probably the better approach. You certainly don't want to expose every single (inherited) method, don't you?

Comment: @igknighton please update your question instead of providing more information in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot put concrete classes in place of generics.  Angle brackets after a class name are used when the author of the class wants the consumer to specify a type. You need to do the following instead.

```
public class CardSet extends LinkedList<FlashCard>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're [hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2) the class definition of `FlashCard`. Remove the 1st generic argument

```
public class CardSet extends LinkedList<FlashCard> {
```